# test three conditions

Tags: conditional

I am a new user of *Mathematica*. Currently I am facing a problem with my coding. I want to test a condition using `If` or any other expression. Let's say I have two lists that I want to test, `A` and `B`; each one of them contain 16 elements. I want to test if `A` is greater than `0` and `B` also greater than zero then write minimum, if `A` is greater than zero and `B` is less than zero then write maximum, else write saddle so my code was like this

```
A={1,0.2,3,4,5,-6,7,8,0,12,-13,14,15,0.16,17,18};
B={3,-2,5,6,7,23,-14,2,7,6,9,4,11,34,0.12,0};
Table[{i,Which[A[[i]]>0 && B[[i]]>0,"Minimum",A[[i]]>0 && B[[i]]<0,"Maximum",A[[i]]==0 && B[[i]]==0,"Saddle"]},{i,1,16}]
```

What I get was something like this: `{{1,Maximum},{2,Null},{28,Null},...}}` - it repeats the same thing.

So would someone help me please to construct the condition correctly?

Comment: What is the desired output? A list like `{"Minimum", "Maximum", "Minimum", ....}`? Your description is a different thing than your code, and the code does not produce the output you showed. What does "it repeats the same thing" mean? If you're concerned with the `Null`s, consider `A[[6]] == -6` and `B[[6]] == 23` - such situation is not present in the code; there's no instruction what to do, hence the `Null`. Overall, it's not very clear what you want to achieve. Please clarify and write explicitly what's the desired output.

Comment: i want it to test the value of A and B  together so if they where greater than zero i want it to print" minimum" and if A is greater than zero and B is not then i want it to print "minimum" and if both of them A and B equal zero i want it to print "saddle' in another word i want it to be something similar to this {Maximum,saddle,Minimum ,.....}  this output is just an example for what i want to produce i want it to test the A and B together  and give me something similar to the output that i wrote

Comment: So your code does exactly that. There are no pairs of corresponding `A[[i]]` and `B[[i]]` that are both equal to zero, hence no `"Saddle"` is printed; but you still have cases when `A[[i]]<0` and `B[[i]]>0` for which you don't specify what should be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much to drew my attention to that

Answer (score 3):

A `Rule` approach (based on the given conditional):

```
Sign[Thread[{A, B}]] /. {{1, 1} -> "Minimum", {1, -1} -> 
   "Maximum", {0, 0} -> "Saddle", {_, _} :> "Indeterminate"}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it seems like there might be some confusion as to what you need, but here is a general recipe you can modify (Since you didn't say anything about if B>0 and A<0 for instance, I sorted the values first so that a "Maximum" is any combination of A or B less than zero with the other greater than 0):

```
test[a_,b_]:=Module[
  {x, y},
  {y, x} = Sort[{a, b}];
  Which[
    x > 0 && y < 0, "Minimum",
    x > 0 && y > 0, "Maximum",
    x == 0 && y == 0, "Saddle",
    True, "Unconsidered Case"
    ]
  ];
```

To use this test do:

```
test@@@Transpose@{A,B}
```

which gives the output:

```
   {"Maximum", "Minimum", "Maximum", "Maximum", "Maximum", "Minimum",
"Minimum", "Maximum", "Unconsidered Case", "Maximum", "Minimum",
"Maximum", "Maximum", "Maximum", "Maximum", "Unconsidered Case"}
```

`Which` returns the first condition that comes back as `True`, so the final statement catches anything not explicitly accounted for. In this case, you don't say what to do if one value is exactly zero and the other is positive or negative.